# kubernetes: Node description and resources

Tags: kubernetes

This is the output of my `kubectl describe node <node-name> -o yaml` command:

```
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests    Limits
  --------                   --------    ------
  cpu                        374m (4%)   3151m (39%)
  memory                     493Mi (1%)  1939Mi (7%)
  ephemeral-storage          0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd  0           0
```

Τhe requests are calculated based on the corresponding pod field? (`resources.requests`) Or is the node able to report the **actual** resource usage?

If the above is not the actual usage, is there a way to get the corresponding actual metrics?

(I mean via `kubectl` and not using something like `prometheus` and `node-exporter`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It corresponds to the requests and limits of the containers running on the node.

To get the actual resource usage of each node, you can use:

```
kubectl top node
```

However, this requires you to install the [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) which exposes these metrics through the [Resource Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md), because `kubectl top` gets these metrics from the Resource Metrics API.

To install the Metrics Server, simply apply [these YAML files](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/tree/master/deploy/1.8%2B).